# extract set of lines using separator from file in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, sed, pattern-matching, text-extraction

I have below 3 queries in a single flat file. i want to extract 1 query from input file(ex: 2nd query) at a time. Separator for each query is ";"(semi colon). Please suggest how can i do this?

**input file:** query.sql

```
select * from 
DBNAME.table1;

select * from 
DBNAME.table2
;

select * from 
DBNAME.table3
WHERE date<= current_date-30;
```

output should be

**Outputfile**: query_out.sql

```
select * from 
DBNAME.table2
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `awk`,

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"} NR==2{print $0}' yourfile.sql > output.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

sat's answer does not trim blank lines between two sql requests, nor does it output the semicolon ending a request.

Provided you are using gawk (or any flavour of awk allowing RS to be a regular expression), the following will probably suit your needs:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=";[[:space:]]*"} NR==2 {printf "%s;\n",$0}' yourfile.sql
```